# Signature does not match - same implementation is working in different env

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, aws-sts

I'm using aws-java-sdk-sts', version: '1.12.166' to try to connect to sqs queue and read messages from it and route them with Apache camel camel-aws-sqs:3.0.0 to a route when I deploy my solution I get the following error:

> Failed polling endpoint: aws-sqs://MY-QUEUE-IN?
> accessKey=AKIXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&autoCreateQueue=false&maxMessagesPerPoll=1&queueUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fsqs.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com%2F111111111111%2FMY-QUEUE-IN-IN&region=EU_CENTRAL_1&secretKey=xxxxxx.
> Will try again at next poll.
> Caused by: [com.amazonaws.services.sqs.model.AmazonSQSException - The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided.
> Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.
> The Canonical String for this request should have been\n'POST\n/111111111111/MY-QUEUE-IN\n\namz-sdk-invocation-id:cc8c4702-664c-e76e-c071-ca02662a9aed\namz-sdk-request:ttl=20220812T181141Z;attempt=1;max=4\namz-sdk-retry:0/0/0\nhost:sqs.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com\nuser-agent:aws-sdk-java/1.12.166 Linux/5.4.172-90.336.amzn2.x86_64 OpenJDK_64-Bit_Server_VM/25.242-b08 java/1.8.0_242 vendor/IcedTea cfg/retry-mode/legacy\nx-amz-date:20220812T181051Z\n\namz-sdk-invocation-id;amz-sdk-request;amz-sdk-retry;host;user-agent;x-amz-date\n62bd803266d1241d4d977f450bc1dec1a924d61a9fe6e7ca76a26c6acf706134'
> The String-to-Sign should have been\n'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256\n20220812T181051Z\n20220812/eu-central-1/sqs/aws4_request\n8d1d936c48bdd037fdc35a20cbcfdc3da6b6275e753d2d821c689ce7690c8de8' (Service: AmazonSQS; Status Code: 403;

The code I use to send the request

```
from("aws-sqs:" + QueueName +
                        "?queueUrl=" + Endpoint + QueueName+
                        "&accessKey=" + AccessKey +
                        "&secretKey=" + SecretKey +
                        "&region=" + Region +
                        "&autoCreateQueue=false" +
                        "&maxMessagesPerPoll=" + pollingMessagesMax
        )
```

I provide these params via config file that I pass:

- QUEUENAME: 'MY-QUEUE-IN'
- ENDPOINT: 'https://sqs.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/111111111111/'
- REGION: 'EU_CENTRAL_1'

and the access and secretKey are defined in my secret.

I'm using the same SDK in a different env with same implementation and it's working only difference I have is in this env I have different access and secretkey

My secret key in this env contains // something like ABCDHERMHHJJJJJq+PU/dGejhdsh/wE7lwHtqjAHJKL

I read that could be the issue

Answer (score 0):

The issue was fixed when I generated a new secretKey that doesn't contains '+' character.somehow the '+' charater in the key was the cause of the issue